# WinSCP: Using GetFiles() encounter Junction Directory

Tags: c++-cli, winscp, junction, winscp-net

[Question] Can WinSCP handle Junction directory?

I am using C++/CLI to program a SFTP program using WinSCP .NET assembly (version 5.5.3). My program reads in a schedule file. Originally the source path for get file has to be absolute path. Now that I have to support relative path, I encounter a problem.

Following is to try to get all text files in the home directory. Of course, I want to get all text files within all sub directories inside home directory as well. So I use:

```
transferOptionObject->FileMask = "*.txt";
transferResult = sftpSession->GetFiles(".", "C:\\temp\\receive", false, 
                 transferOptionObject);
```

Suppose we use this account **terry** to log in the remote computer, the remote home directory is `/C/Users/terry/Documents`.  From the `session->DebugLog` file, I find out WinSCP tries to go over all files and directories within the home directory.

The list is:

```
* a.txt
* firstDirectory
* My Music
* My Photos
* My Videso
* OtherDirectory
* Other.txt
```

WinSCP goes over each item in the list. After processing `firstDirectory`, it tries to process `My Music`. However it returns an error as not able to process because of Permission Denied.

I then go to the server, and do a `dir`. I find out those 3 'My' directories are [Junction] as:

```
29-Apr-14  09:44    <DIR>          .
29-Apr-14  09:44    <DIR>          ..
16-Jan-14  09:48    <DIR>          Documents
16-Jan-14  09:45    <JUNCTION>     My Music [C:\Users\terry\Music]
16-Jan-14  09:45    <JUNCTION>     My Pictures [C:\Users\terry\Pictures]
16-Jan-14  09:45    <JUNCTION>     My Videos [C:\Users\terry\Videos]
```

I go over these and find out these:
[Topic "Sync is broken"](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13461) ;; [Tracker Bug 1132](http://winscp.net/tracker/1132) ;; [Topic: "WinSCP doesn't check hardlink target date when synchronizing"](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8058)

Are they related?

Answer (score 0):

As it's a remote junction/folder, and the SFTP protocol does not know anything about junctions, it's all about your SFTP server. This has nothing to do with client (WinSCP), as it cannot even know it's a junction. Your SFTP server most likely simply presents the junction as a folder. Although it could also present it as a symlink to a folder (but in that case WinSCP would silently skip it).

---

*Side note: The path to the remote target directory should end with a slash.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles*

Comment: 1) Luckily, user of my program says there should not be any case of getting files using wildcard (e.g. *.txt) in the home directory. 2) My program has to handle the relative path! So I use `"."` 3) For path must end with slash/backslash, both these are successful. Case a) Get file, file with wildcard, I use `GetFiles(dir name before wildcard file without ending /, local dir name without ending \\)`. Case b) Get file, file without wildcard, I use `GetFiles(full path with file name, local dir name with \\)`. For SyncDir, I get correct  result with no ending slash/backslash.